# PATCH request for SCIM 2.0

Tags: json, rest, scim, scim2

We are sending PATCH request to a server in SCIM specification.

As per the SCIM specifications, the request should contain following attributes in PATCH request.

- op
- path
- value

So if we are changing the '**givenName**' attribute from core schema then the PATCH request will be in following way, (ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.5.2)

```
{
 "schemas" : ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
     "Operations":[
       {
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"name.givenName",
        "value":"Ravindra"
       }
     ]
}
```

Now what should be the '**path**' attribute if are modifying any SCIM extension, let's say enterprise extension.

Is the following representation is correct for enterprise extension?

```
{
 "schemas" : ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
     "Operations":[
       {
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:user.department",
        "value":"Engineering"
       }
     ]
}
```

Comment: can we also do it like below

`
"Operations":[
       {
        "op":"replace",
     "path":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:user",
        "value":{"department":"Engineering"}
       }
     ]
`

Like I also happen to have similar requirement but want your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the ABNF to which scim filters should adhere (see section 3.4.2.2 of RFC 7644), when you refer to an attribute part of an extension you should do URI:attribute_path, so in your case this is "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:department"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when attempting to PATCH the "active" value of an enterprise user. The solution is simple: change your "path" value in the example above to simply "department".

For completeness, here's the PATCH body that worked for me in Postman:

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
  ],
  "Operations": [
     {
       "op":"replace",
       "path":"active",
       "value":"false"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute '.Operations.[].value' must be of type hash

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "value": {
        "active": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this will work!!